# Center Google Maps (V3) on browser resize (responsive)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Maps (V3) in my page at 100% page width with one marker in the middle. When I resize my browser window's width I would like the map to stay centered (responsive). Now the map just stays at the left side of the page and gets smaller.

UPDATE
Got it to work exactly as described thanks to duncan. This is the final code:

```
var center;
function calculateCenter() {
  center = map.getCenter();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
  calculateCenter();
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  map.setCenter(center);
});
```

Comment: good job! yes you have to continuously output the current center value to global scope so it can be picked up by the dom listener

Comment: If you are going top do it this way, then `center` does not need to be global. Providing `center` (and `calculateCenter`) are in the same scope as `map`, then everything should work. Of course, if `map` is global then you'll need to fix that too :)

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to most, but this code comes AFTER the map is loaded, so it should be at least on windows.onload

Comment: thanks, this should be the default google maps beaviours

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You need to have an event listener for when the window resizes.  This worked for me (put it in your initialize function):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    map.setCenter(center);
});
```

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! But if someone has moved the map, how do I get the new center of the map? I found the getCenter() function, but can't get it to work correctly. map.setCenter(map.getCenter()); doesn't work.

Comment: You want another event listener, I think for "center_changed" on the map object, that updates a global variable with the new coordinates, which you can then use in your setCenter.

Comment: I tried that as well:

`var center;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
  center = map.getCenter();
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  map.setCenter(center);
});`

Doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about "bounds_changed" instead?

Comment: No change. It doesn't seem to accept the center var's value I think. I also tried: `var lat = center.lat();
var lng = center.lng();
var center2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
map.setCenter(center2);` Doesn't work either.

Comment: You might need a closure: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventClosures

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6586/discussion-between-gregory-bolkenstijn-and-duncan)

Comment: This is the easiest way: http://hsmoore.com/blog/keep-google-map-v3-centered-when-browser-is-resized/

Comment: Guys addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() { does not worked for me :(

Comment: @duncan it worked but I had to add it with orientationchange event

Comment: 0x616f's solution is the best, because it also works when clicking the maximize/restore's window button, which doesn't with the main solution.

Answer (score 83):

Detect the browser resize event, resizes the Google Map while preserving the center point:

```
var map = ...; // your map initialisation code

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center); 
});
```

You can use the same code in other event handlers when resizing the google map via other means (e.g. with a jQuery-UI 'resizable' control).

Source: http://ataiva.com/keep-google-map-v3-centered-when-browser-is-resized/ credit to [@smftre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792676/center-google-maps-v3-on-browser-resize-responsive#comment21566492_8792945) for the link.

*Note: This code was linked in @smftre's comment on the accepted answer. I think it's worth adding it as its own answer since it is really superior to the accepted answer. It eliminates the need of a global variable to track the center point and an event handler to update that variable.*

Comment: Agree with @William, this method results in a more accurate center-position when the map is resized.

Comment: accepted answer wasn't working correctly, this one did the trick

Comment: This is the best and working solution. Works on every resize windows event. Other solutions didnt work properly.

Comment: This really should have been posted as community wiki.

Comment: It works, but I'd like to understand it more. What precisely does `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` ?

Comment: @WilliamDenniss link was updated to: http://hsmoore.com/blog/keep-google-map-v3-centered-when-browser-is-resized/

Answer (score 4):

Some good examples on w3schools.com. I used the following and it works great.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  map.panTo(myLatlng);
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_events.asp

Answer (score 0):

html: Create a div with an id of your choice

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

js: Create a map and attach it to the div you just created

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856)
});
```

Center when the window resizes

```
var center = map.getCenter();

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    map.setCenter(center);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated of the above solution to es6.

```
let center;
const addMapListener = google.maps.event.addDomListener;

addMapListener(map, 'idle', () => center = map.getCenter());
addMapListener(window, 'resize', () => map.setCenter(center));
```

Comment: You're using the `addDomListener` for both the `window`, which is a DOM element, and the `map`, which isn't.  The map object should use the `google.maps.event.addListener` or its own `map.addListener` event handler.