# Google map not showing when in a hidden div

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, responsive-design, enquire.js

I know this is a common issue reported on this site and elsewhere e.g.

- http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/google-maps-in-hidden-div
- http://dougmolineux.com/wp/?p=242

But I can't get my issue solved.

So I've got a responsive site built Mobile first and I'm trying to get an adaptive map solution working i.e. mobile viewports get a static Google map image and for non-mobile viewports the full Google map API and this all has to update itself when the viewport resizes not just on page load. Based on this: http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/tLxAs.

I'm using [**this library**](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/).

I'm conditionally loading the Maps API only when it's needed (non-mobile viewports) via jQuery's `$.getScript` and the libraries `setup()` and `defer()` functions.

So that there's only the right map rendering at each viewport I'm using jQuery `hide()` and `show()` because of this the API map won't fully load itself (just 1 tile), well it does load fine if the page loads at a non-mobile viewport size, it's when you resize to mobile viewport back to non-mobile viewport size as that's when the `show()` method kicks in. Everything else works fine.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="map">
    <div class="map__static">
        <img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.867487,151.20699&zoom=15&markers=-33.867487,151.20699&size=650x405&sensor=false">
    </div>
</div>
```

The static map image is loaded by default as the site is built Mobile first.

**JS**

```
var mapContainer = $('.map'),
mapStaticContainer = $('.map__static');
mapDynamicContainer = $('<div class="map__dynamic"/>');

// Start Enquire library
enquire.register('screen and (min-width: 40em)', {

    deferSetup: true,

    setup: function setup() {
        mapContainer.prepend(mapDynamicContainer);
        mapDynamicContainer.load('/includes/scripts/adaptive-google-map.php', function() {
            $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAywjPmf5WvWh_cIn35NwtIk-gYuwu1I2Q&sensor=false&callback=initialize');
        });
    },

    // Not mobile size viewport
    match: function() {
        mapStaticContainer.hide();
        mapDynamicContainer.show();
    },

    // Mobile size viewport
    unmatch: function() { 
        mapStaticContainer.show();
        mapDynamicContainer.hide();
    }

}, true).listen();
```

This is the contents of **'/includes/scripts/adaptive-google-map.php'** which is AJAX'd in via jQuery `load()`.

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867487,151.20699);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: false
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    var contentString = 
        '<div class="infowindow">'+
            '<div>'+
                    '<p class="flush"><strong>SALES OFFICE:</strong><br>1/16 M. 5<br>Sydney<br>NSW, 83110.</p>'
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'
    ;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    // Center Google Maps (V3) on browser resize (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792676/center-google-maps-v3-on-browser-resize-responsive)
    var center;
    function calculateCenter() {
        center = map.getCenter();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        calculateCenter();
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
    }
</script>
```

This fixes the problem:

```
mapDynamicContainer.show(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
    initialize(); 
}, 100);
 })
```

But throws a JS error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined`. Another common fix suggested by ppl. is applying this: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` but when I put that after: `mapDynamicContainer.show();` in the `match()` function I get this JS error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`.

Not having much luck :(

Comment: Hey Chris, Nick here ;-) Did you see that none other that Chris Coyier covered this exact scenario recently on CSS tricks? He even uses enquire.js! You may be interested in having a look here: http://css-tricks.com/workshop-notes-webstock-13/

Comment: Also, he covers the same here, in a little more detail: http://css-tricks.com/deseret-digital-workshop/

Comment: Thanks for those links Nick but there's no mention of the issue I'm having even though they were good reads ;) I did try Chris's technique where he's using jQuery `.load()` to load in each map version (img/iframe) which fixes my problem (map API not fully rendering going from `match` -> `unmatch` -> `match`) however I can't use `.load()` each time in `match` as I'm loading in the full API (non-iframe) so each time I'm in `match` the API re-downloads itself which ain't great for performance + Google fires a warning in the console about this. So I download it once via `setup` then [cont..]

Comment: use `hide`/`show` to show the relevant map (img/API) and this is the issue when going from `match` -> `unmatch` -> `match` [**as explained here**](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/google-maps-in-hidden-div). All the suggested fixes aren't working.

Comment: To fix I need to call the Google Map API `initialize();` function inside `match` but the `initialize();` function is undefined here because it exists in the file I'm AJAX'ing in via `.load()`
`mapDynamicContainer.load('/includes/scripts/adaptive-google-map.php', function({ $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAywjPmf5WvWh_cIn35NwtIk-gYuwu1I2Q&sensor=false&callback=initialize');});` and the Google maps API is being loaded asynchronously via `getScript`. Basically I need access to that `initialize();` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so basically the "resize" is still your answer.

I just modified your match to this piece of code:

```
match: function() {
    mapStaticContainer.hide();
    mapDynamicContainer.show();
    if( typeof(map) != 'undefined'){
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    }
 },
```

and it's working. 
don't know if you have any other stuff in your code. I used html, js, and content of adaptive-google-map.php you provide and it works without any problems.