# Cannot load in Google Map lat/long coordinates from outside external initialize script

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931819/google-map-not-showing-when-in-a-hidden-div) to see the code set-up which **all works fine**.

I'm working on a real-estate site that uses this exact same adaptive map solution but I have many pages in the site requiring a map (property detail pages) so I need a way to embed the lat/long coordinates within each property detail page and have the external `initialize()` script pick it up but I can't get this to work.

I added 2 `lat`/`long` var's to the `initialize()` script:

```
function initialize(lat, long) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
```

and then on the page needing a map I tried this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (typeof(map) != 'undefined') {
             initialize(-33.867487,151.20699);
        }
    }
</script>
```

But the coordinates aren't picked up:
[image]

I'm sure it's related to how everything is loading in **i.e.** the `initialize()` script is being AJAX'd in via jQuery `load()` then once that is loaded the Maps API loads in via jQuery's `$.getScript` and this all happens on `$(window).load`. I'm just stuck on how the lat/long coordinates can tie in with this set-up?

**--EDIT--**

I'll break down the code set-up as easy as I can:

In my external global JS file I've got this to set-up the adaptive Google Map solution which uses the [**Enquire JS**](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) library:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var mapContainer = $('.map'),
    mapStaticContainer = $('.map__static'),
    mapDynamicContainer = $('<div class="map__dynamic"/>');

    /* --Enquire library-- */
    enquire.register(BPlap, {

        deferSetup: true,

        setup: function() {
            mapContainer.prepend(mapDynamicContainer);
            mapDynamicContainer.html('<span class="preloader"><span class="preloader__spinner"></span> <em>Loading map&#8230;</em></span>').load('/includes/modules/adaptive-google-map/js.php', function() {
                $.getScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize', function(){});
            });
        },

        // Not palm size viewport
        match: function() {
            mapStaticContainer.hide();
            mapDynamicContainer.show();
            // Need this so the map fully renders when going from `match` -> `unmatch` -> `match`
            if (typeof(map) != 'undefined') {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                map.setCenter(center);
            }
        },

        // Palm size viewport
        unmatch: function() {   
            mapStaticContainer.show();
            mapDynamicContainer.hide();
        }

    }, true).listen();

});
```

The contents of the file AJAX'd in via jQuery `load()`: **/includes/modules/adaptive-google-map/js.php**:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
//function initialize() {
function initialize(lat, long) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867487, 151.20699);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: false
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    // Center Google Maps on browser resize (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792676/center-google-maps-v3-on-browser-resize-responsive)
    var center;
    function calculateCenter() {
        center = map.getCenter();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        calculateCenter();
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
}
</script>
```

If I hardcode the lat/long coords in the `initialize()` script above (commented out lines) everything works fine it's when I'm trying to pass in the `lat` / `long` var's from within the page the map is being inserted that I can't do.

Comment: You have to do more than just create a LatLng object to get Google Maps to initialise, can you post the rest of that function?

Comment: See my other question for the entire code set-up (link above) including the `initialize()` script.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to remove the vars from here:

```
function initialize(lat, long) {
```

So it was just this:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
```

Then just have this inline JS on the page the map was being used:

```
<script>
var lat     = 53.43072,
    long    = -3.049134;
</script>
```