# Focus a responsive Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've looked at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792676/center-google-maps-v3-on-browser-resize-responsive) and implemented the answer in the actual question.

But get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

I'm adding my map by embedding an iframe, also my JS is not run until

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I think google check you APIKEY before.

Try the method describe in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) passing a callback inside the scrips tag ;)

```html
  <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}

</script>
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question.

Comment: When I try to help you, I suggest you to read correctly. if your `google` object is null that's because your script is not ready, this ensure `google`  to be ready...

Comment: But Im not embedding by a script, I suggest you read the question correctly.

Comment: In this case we have not enough details in your question. Why trying to play with the API if you don't include the API ?